# async SMS from asp.net using twilio

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, twilio

I have an asp.net web application that notifies business clients about available appointments. 
The scenario is as below.

1. Page button click event handler saves new appointment to the database
2. Preferences of registered clients are matched to the new appointment created
3. Clients whose preferences match are sent an SMS message through Twilio with the appointment details.

My problem is that I need to separate steps 2 & 3 from the page's execution. So once an appointment is created the following steps are passed on asynchronously to a helper class which handles the matching and SMS messaging on a background thread, while the page control returns and the user is redirected to another page. The background class method doesn't return any value (public void).

Sorry for not posting the code earlier.

createappointment.aspx.cs

```
  private void SaveAppointment()
{
    using (var db = new EntitiesModel())
    {
       //code to create a new appointment

     //Sending SMS messages to multiple clients

        SMSHelper myhelper = new SMSHelper();
        myhelper.SendApptSMS(newappt);

        //control returned to the page redirect to dashboard
        Response.Redirect("~/authuser/default.aspx");
    }
}
```

smshelper.cs

```
public async void SendApptSMS(Appointment newappointment)
{
    using (var db = new EntitiesModel())
    {
        //retrieve multiple clients that match preferences
    foreach (var item in clients)
   {
      //for each client send SMS message using Twilio's REST API
    }
        //Thread.Sleep(10000);

    }
}
```

I expect page to continue processing once the call to the async method has been made, which then executes on a background thread.
This doesn't happen.
The response.redirect is not reached until the SMSHelper has finished sending out all the messages.

Hope this clears up the problem.

Comment: So many options - using threads, events/mq/pubsub, etc.

Comment: background treads are problematic in asp.net. In Azure, you can use Web Jobs. See http://curah.microsoft.com/52143/using-the-webjobs-feature-of-windows-azure-web-sites

Answer (score -1):

Why not have a separate service or background task that runs once a minute (or so) in the background and runs the SendApptSMS() method?